# product of probabilities converging to zero

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

About the problem

"Suppose the random variables $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ are distributed according to $P_B$. Let $P_A$ denote any other probability distribution, and consider the likelihood ratio 
\begin{align}
\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{P_A(X_i)}{P_B(X_i)}
\end{align}
of the first $n$ observations. Show that this likelihood ratio converges to $0$ with probability one as $n\rightarrow\infty$ and interpret this result."

The teacher said we can better write it as sums and logarithm.
So we must show
\begin{align}
\log(\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{P_A(X_i)}{P_B(X_i)})\rightarrow -\infty
\end{align}
My try was then to use expectation as follows:
the $X_i$ can only be discrete, otherwise we are done or we get dividing by $0$. So the expectation of this $\log$ is a countable sum.

This is equal to $E_B \Big(\sum_{i=1}^n \log(P_A(X_i)-\sum_{i=1}^n \log(P_B(X_i)\Big) = \sum_i E_B\Big(\log P_A(X_i)-\log P_B(X_i)\Big)$
so we are done if for all $i$ it holds that 
\begin{align}
E(\log P_A(X_i)-\log P_B(X_i))<c 
\end{align}
for certain $c$, which is to show $\sum_x P_B(X_i=x)\Big( \log P_A(X_i=x)-\log P_B(X_i=x)\Big)<c$
Intuitively it is clear that: there are positive values and negative values for $\log P_A (X_i=x)-\log P_B(X_i=x)$ and the positives have a small weight $P_B(X_i=x)$ relative to $P_A(X_i=x)$ while the negatives have a relative big weight. And the negatives and positives will neutralise since the sums $\sum_x P_{A}(X_i=x)$ and $\sum_x P_B(X_i=x)$ are $1$.

Does anyone have suggestions? I thank in advance because I can't do that in the comments and of course because I wanna be grateful.